# Using double quotes in an HTML page's input's value

Tags: html

How can I include double quotes in an HTML page's input's value?

Eg: `<input name="locations[]" value="["SFO","SJO","LA"]">`

I need double quotes there, because this is a json array. But it wont work. Changing it to `'` causes errors in the json.

I'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode the value using html entities.

HTML Entity for `"` is `&quot;`

So, in your case, the result would look like this:

`<input name="locations[]" value="[&quot;SFO&quot;,&quot;SJO&quot;,&quot;LA&quot;]">`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
<input name="locations[]" value="[&quot;SFO&quot;,&quot;SJO&quot;,&quot;LA&quot;]">
```

`&quot;` is processed as `&#34;` which is **ISO 8859-1** equivalent of `"`. You may also refer [this](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html#quot)